# How do I include a GWT module from a sibling project?

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I have project A that contains all the domain objects shared between multiple projects. Along side it is project B based on GWT which I would like to use client side.

Based on the reading I've done, here is how I've currently set it up:

Project A:
com.foo.bar.domain.* -> contains the objects

Project B:
Has a dependancy on project A through Maven.
com.foo.bar.Domain.gwt.xml:

```
<module>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
    <source path="domain" />
</module>
```

and the main module contains:

```
<inherits name="com.eyereturn.operations.Operations"/>
```

Yet I'm still getting the following when I attempt to run the code-server

```
No source code is available for type com.foo.bar.domain.User; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Answer (score 1):

With the details you provided, I can only suggest setting the source path to an absolute path. (you can also try something like "./domain")

Comment: Would have thought the absolute path would at least work, but alas no. Still not finding the object. WAIT. Does it matter if the object in question is an enum?

Answer (score 1):

The Error which you are getting is because Project A is not able to find the "Module" of Project B.Follow the below steps

1. Project A contains Module a(com.project.example.a)
2. project B contains Module b(com.project.example.b)
3. Add the dependency of Project B in project A(pom.xml)
4. inherit the Module of Project B into Project A like `<inherits name="com.project.example.b"/>`

Comment: Project B is already a dependancy in project A. And I don't think the inherit example you gave works without an explicit b.gwt.xml file in project B, which I've already tried to no avail. Thanks though.

Comment: Plz refer this link http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideInheritingModules ..to include module inside module

Answer (score 0):

> No source code is available for type com.foo.bar.domain.User; did you forget to inherit a required module?

At a compile time,`B` is not able to find `User` package structure that you have used. so it gives such error.

You can either make gwt project where `User` class exist or needs to create another common project for no of bean that can be share into `A` and `B` project. after that you have to inherit common project into `B.gwt.xml`